# Adobe Flash Player not detected on Chromium for Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, flash, chromium, adobe

I am using Chromium for Ubuntu and it's telling me I need to install Adobe Flash Player (AFP) when I go to play a certain video by directing me to Adobe's website. I have AFP installed via Ubuntu Software Center, however that seems to be not good enough.

How can I get it working?

I have done some research before posting this and I'm being told (from Adobe's website) to download the tar ball, extract, then cp the files into certain directories, namely libflashplayer.so into Chromium's "browser plug-in directory" and a /usr folder into "the flash player local settings configuration."

I presume this process will work given that it's in Adobe's readme file; I have a few questions about the instructions. How do I find the browser plugin in directory, generally speaking; I'd like an answer that applies to any OS as well as browser if possible.

If there is a better way to go about solving this problem, please address it.

Answer (score -2):

You could just use Chrome instead of Chromium, if you need a browser to work with flash out of the box. (I am not sure about Chromium, but am using Chrome and I have Flash built in which works fine.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @guntbert I think this is an answer, not a comment; I've edited to clarify. (The question here may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and even if this answer is considered lacking, [it would not be more appropriate as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).)